# Google IMAP Is Slow, there is a way to make it faster?

Tags: outlook, g-suite, imap, gmail

i have gmail account about 3 years, its got 10,000+ messages there, i installed outlook today and i tried to use IMAP Feature (i enabled it before coupule of years)
the problem its very very slow. is there is somthing i can do ? and what is the diffrenence between google apps and hosted exchange?

Comment: Faster connection, archive unneeded message so there's not so much to index,...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just erase the word "Google" in your question. IMAP is slow. IMAP in general is fast but you can mess with it to make it slow.

So having 10,000+ (even 1,000+) in one folder (Inbox is a folder) slows it down to make it nearly unusable. To get around this you *have to* organize your mails in folders and subfolders. Luckily Google hides this subfolder thing from you by renaming the procedure: In the Google world it is a "label". Label and tag your mails and they automatically go in subfolders. Read the mails there and not the "All-Messages-Folder".

Another way to make it faster is drop Outlook! Outlook is one of the worst IMAP clients in the world. It can handle IMAP but it doesn't make it right.

If you now say: "But I need them in one folder and don't want to throw away Outlook!" then I have to say: "Complain to Google and Microsoft".

Comment: So Hosted Exchange Service can do a better job?

Comment: With 10,000+ mails in one folder? No.

Comment: Re: Hosted exchange; yes, up to a certain point. Exchange uses MAPI, a proprietary protocol that performs better than IMAP (particularly if Outlook's IMAP is slow). However with 10,000 emails you still risk getting slowed down by the local cache management in Outlook. Even with a fast PC and SSD, very large folders eventually become slow. TL;DR: archive emails or move them to sub-folders.